# In Mission Control, is there a way to set-off desktops, to distinctly differentiate them?

Tags: desktop, mission-control

I regularly have 5 to 8 desktops open. Until recently, I've been using them for apps that are visually distinct, so in Mission Control I could tell which desktop had which apps and documents simply by glancing. Now, however, each desktop hosts the same app and all of the desktops look alike, making it difficult to tell which has which project on it. (I shift them around based on priority as the week goes on.)

I'm wondering if there's a way to highlight or otherwise set-off desktops——say, by having different colored borders around different ones, much like tags work.

(I'm running 10.15.6.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to give each one a different background. You could have a background of a single color and change the color for different spaces. You could even make a solid colored image with a large number on it like 1, or 5 and make 10 of these images. Then give each space a different number background.

Comment: I've looked into this before, and unless something's changed, this is the only way to do this. Just have different desktop images for each Space.